# How to remove proudly created by WordPress in theme?

Tags: theme-development, themes

How to remove proudly created by WordPress in theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete it from the footer.php file or you can hide the CSS that displays it which is better in case you update the theme as the footer.php file may get over-written.

If you choose the CSS route, then paste the following into your CSS file:

```
#site-generator {
    display: none;
}
```